# Is there a debugger that will trace into ring-0 code?

Tags: debugging

Is there a debugger these days that will trace beyond a syscall or sysenter into ring-0 code? Or is there a technique using a debugger like Windbg? I have read that if you get close enough to the syscall/sysenter function, then set a BP in ring-0 code windbg will break in ring-0.

Comment: https://github.com/HyperDbg/HyperDbg

Comment: Thanks for link...will check it out.